# Problems with CSV

Tags: csv

I can't upload my inventory to RepairShopr, CSV Lint says: `Unexpected whitespace on row 2`

My CSV looks like this:

```
1445767;TastaturMacbookAir11;Tastatur;FALSE;0;;;2016-01-13 21:23:49 +0100;2016-01-13 21:24:12 +0100;;FALSE;2;TRUE;;;;;;;;;17605;;;FALSE;;1900;00.00;00.00;"Macbook Air;Macbook Air 11"
```

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Hey Oliver, can you include the header row for the CSV file in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Replace double quotes by single quotes like this

```
1445767;TastaturMacbookAir11;Tastatur;FALSE;0;;;2016-01-13 21:23:49 +0100;2016-01-13 21:24:12 +0100;;FALSE;2;TRUE;;;;;;;;;17605;;;FALSE;;1900;00.00;00.00;'Macbook Air;Macbook Air 11'
```